# tar -x -v -f on tape drive in Ubuntu (latest)

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I am given the following command:

tar -x -v -f /dev/rct0 -b 20 *

Could someone please explain its meaning, because in this form it looks completely useless to me. As far as I know -x stands for extract. So, take all files (?) from the current dir and extract them to the type drive rct0? If so, what is the -b 20 flag doing there? (use the maximum size block size when writing?) I would have tried it myself, unfortunately I don't have a tape drive. I hope someone will shed some light on what is going on here. Happy holidays everyone! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `tar --help`:

- `-x` tells `tar` to extract files.
- `-v` makes it verbose.
- `-f /dev/rct0` specifies the file to extract from.
- `-b 20` specifies the blocking factor. *(obsolete, since `20` is the default)*
- Finally, `*` instructs `tar` to extract all files that are present in the current directory.

A shorter command to achieve the same action would be:

```
tar xvf /dev/rct0 *
```

Regarding the blocking factor:

> The data in an archive is grouped into blocks, which are `512` bytes. Blocks are read and written in whole number multiples called records. The number of blocks in a record (i.e., the size of a record in units of `512` bytes) is called the blocking factor. The `--blocking-factor=512-size` (`-b 512-size`) option specifies the blocking factor of an archive. The default blocking factor is typically `20` (i.e., `10240` bytes), but can be specified at installation. To find out the blocking factor of an existing archive, use `tar --list --file=archive-name`. This may not work on some devices.

Source: [The Blocking Factor of an Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking-Factor.html)

Answer (score 2):

From tar manpage:

```
 -x, --extract, --get
       extract files from an archive
 -b, --blocking-factor BLOCKS
       BLOCKS x 512 bytes per record
 -f, --file ARCHIVE
       use archive file or device ARCHIVE
 -v, --verbose
       verbosely list files processed
```

So this command reads data from tapedrive (`-f /dev/rct0`), interprets it as tar-archive and extracts (`-x`) all files which are already present in current directory (`*`). Blocking factor is most likely adjusted to optimize tapedrive performance (haven't worked with them either).